# Kotlin with Map in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
var view: View = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, null)!!

var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment?=null
mapFragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

return view
}
```

Logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
at example.com.kotlinexamplebydimple.Mapfragment.onCreateView(Mapfragment.kt:36)
```

on this line the error is showing :

```
mapFragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
```

Comment: did initialized the fragmentManager

Comment: its getFragmentManager method it is directly used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declared `mapFragment` to be nullable so you have to deal with it:

```
var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment?=null
mapFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
```

Comment: With that use you could declare `mapFragment` to be a `val`. As you're only assigning it once it's safer as it prevents you from reassigning it to another value. The IDE will probably tell you that

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that you try to cast a `null` to `SupportMapFragment`. So, it will be safer to check the type first.

```
val mapFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)
if (mapFragment is SupportMapFragment) {
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val mapFragment: SupportMapFragment? = map as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
}




override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {

    if (googleMap != null) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }

    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

Comment: use in kotlin android release version